# View Magento 1.9 custom attributes in custom block

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-attributes

I would **print** just some **custom attributes** in a custom module block.

I used this code in custom block:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="attributesView" template="catalog/product/view/short_attributes.phtml"}}
```

I've created short_attributes.phtml with this code (took by attributes.phtml):

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct();
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()):
if (!($_product->isGrouped())) :
?>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
  <div class="right_col_features">
    <div class="title_features">DIMENSIONI IMBALLO</div>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data):
            if (($this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['code'])) == "pesoart") 
            ){
                ?><p class="p_features"><span class='subtitle_features'>Peso articolo (kg):</span> <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></p>
            <?php
            }
            if (($this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['code'])) == "volume") ){
            ?><p class="p_features"><span class='subtitle_features'>Volume (mc):</span> <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></p>
            <?php
            }
        endforeach; ?>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): 
            if (($this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['code'])) == "inf01") && $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])== "3"):
        ?><p class='ord24h'>Acquistabile in 30 gg</p>
        <?php
            endif;
        endforeach; ?>
   </div>
</div>
<?php endif;
endif;
?>
```

But I see nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below block code to show your attributes.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="attributesView" template="catalog/product/view/short_attributes.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Nope, but thank you!

Comment: @GiovanniFossati, Check updated block code. I have checked and its working on Magento 1.9

Comment: Yeah, great! @JaiminSutariya you're my hero! Thanks a lot!